# Validating JSON response using rest client

Tags: json, ruby, automated-tests, cucumber, rest-client

I am trying to use rest client in ruby to parse json but I am stuck how to validate the response (extract values from the response). Also I am trying to validate the valid response code(200) response.code does not work.
Following is the JSON response and Code that uses rest client to get it:

```
def self.call_legacy_transactions

  get_response=RestClient::Request.execute(method: :get, url: 'URL', timeout: 15)
  puts(get_response.body)
  json_response = JSON.parse(get_response)
//Dont know how to get the values from response hash. Please suggest

  end
```

JSON Response:

```
    [
  {
    "value": "12345678912345",
    "events": [
      {
        "transaction_id": 205,
        "package_name": "",
        "event_codes": [
          465,
          469,
          471,
          474,
          410,
          490,
          1040
        ]
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 204,
        "package_name": "",
        "event_codes": [
          465,
          469,
          474,
          490
        ]
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 207,
        "package_name": "",
        "event_codes": [
          465,
          469,
          471,
          474,
          490
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want the event code for each transaction for each value.

Comment: Can you give us a better sense of your desired output? Just a list of event codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a flat list of event code integers, you can use:

```
json_response.flat_map do |value_data|
  value_data[:events].flat_map do |event_data|
    event_data[:event_codes]
  end
end
```

**UPDATE** based on the comment "I want to extract event codes only where transaction id is 205":

If there could only ever be one item with that transaction ID:

```
json_response.flat_map do |value_data|
  value_data[:events].find do |event_data|
    event_data[:transaction_id] == 205
  end[:event_codes]
end
```

If there could be many items with that transaction ID:

```
json_response.flat_map do |value_data|
  value_data[:events].select do |event_data|
    event_data[:transaction_id] == 205
  end.flat_map do |event_data|
    event_data[:event_codes]
  end
end
```

Comment: I want to extract event codes only where transaction id is 205

Comment: @RV_Dev, I've updated my answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can call methods on the response to see the body, the response code, etc. More info in the [README](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/master/README.md)

Add to your code:

```
def self.call_legacy_transactions(tx_id = 205)
  get_response=RestClient::Request.execute(method: :get, url: 'URL', timeout: 15)
  puts(get_response.body)

  # check if the response was successful
  if get_response.code == 200
    # need to parse the body
    json_response = JSON.parse(get_response.body)

    # the json response is an array of json objects
    # we need to iterate over them and grab the value
    # in the `events` key and iterate over those and
    # select just the ones with the desired transaction id and
    # get the value in each of the `event_codes` keys and
    # then flatten all the sub arrays into one
    event_codes = json_response.flat_map do |data|
      data['events'].
        select { |event| event['transaction_id'] == tx_id }.
        flat_map { |event| event['event_codes'] }
    end

    event_codes # is now a list of just the event codes
  end
end
```

With the above you can pass the transaction id into the method to get the event codes for any transaction e.g.

```
call_legacy_transactions 205
```

Comment: @DiegoSalazaar: I want to extract event codes only where transaction id is 205

Comment: @RV_Dev Updated the answer